# iphone navigation controller & detailView error

Tags: iphone, objective-c

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/taxsmart/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.2/Applications/34FB8AA4-FB2A-420B-A6E2-220BCF9CD364/practice_plist.app> (loaded)' with name ' DetailView''`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you pasted in your error verbatim, it looks like you have a leading space before DetailView. I've run into this before; simple fix is to open the view which is trying to load DetailView in Interface Builder and fix the "NIB Name" field for DetailView's view controller to not have a leading space.